# Proper CSS to change color of text in parent LI of nested UL

Tags: css

I cannot figure out how to change the color of text in a parent LI (the text "Black") from a child UL nested within the LI. Here is my HTML code:

```
<nav>
<ul class="nav-main">
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Etc</a></li>
<li class="dropdown active"><a href="#">Black</a></li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="green"><a href="#">Green</a></li>
    <li class="red"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
    <li class="purple"><a href="#">Purple</a></li>
    </ul>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Etc</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
nav ul.nav-main li.active > a,
nav ul.nav-main li.active > a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

nav ul.nav-main ul.dropdown-menu li.green > a {
    color: #78AB46;
}

nav ul.nav-main ul.dropdown-menu li.red > a {
    color: #ff0000;
}

nav ul.nav-main ul.dropdown-menu li.purple > a {
    color: #7D26CD;
}
```

And here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/X4eFP

What I would like to happen is that when the mouse hovers over any LI in the child UL "dropdown-menu", that the parent LI "dropdown active" text ("Black") turns from its current color black, to the color blue. I'm not sure how to climb up the parent/child ladder to edit the parent's text color. I only know how to edit the text color of the class the mouse is currently hovering over (not its parent).

I've tried editing my CSS for a couple of hours, and cannot come to any conclusion.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's no parent selector in css, so you can't do what you want without using javascript. Take a look at jQuery's [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't traverse up the DOM tree with CSS (in other words, you can't select the parent node of an element), so you won't be able to do this the way you asked. What you could do though is add a `:hover` style to the `<li>` itself:

```
nav ul.nav-main .dropdown.active:hover > a {
    color:blue;
}
```

This way you are not selecting the `<ul>`, but the parent `<li>` itself. Then you can select the `<a>` inside that `<li>` via the direct-child selector `>`. You will have to nest the `<ul>` inside the actual `<li>` though. You can't place an `<ul>` directly inside another `<ul>` (or `<ol>`).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X4eFP/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Your html is incorrect for a dropdown list.

```
<li class="dropdown active"><a href="#">Black</a>  /*removed the </li> from here */
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="green"><a href="#">Green</a></li>
        <li class="red"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
        <li class="purple"><a href="#">Purple</a></li>
        </ul>
</li> /* put the </li> here */
```

Like others have said, you can't style the parent in CSS. However, when you put the parent `</li>` below the sub menu list/unordered list , then any time you hover over the submenu you are still hovering over that li (black).

CSS

```
.dropdown:hover { 
    color: blue;
 }
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/X4eFP/1/

You'll notice in the demo that the circle of the list is changing from black to blue now.

Still working on the text changing (the text is part of a href link) , seems some css styles are overwriting it from changing blue currently.

Comment: I appreciate the insight.